# How to handle "Could not open a connection to SQL Server" with custom message in vb.net

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, database-connection

Is there any way to provide your own message to the user in case SQL Server Database is offline or not accessible while loading a VB.NET form!
and yeah I don't want to use Try/Catch because it will show all type of error that occurs for example:

```
Try
catch ex as exception
MessageBox.Show("Not Completed Because OF The Following Error " & "%" & ex.Message & "%", "Error", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
end try
```

But if there is a way to use Try&Catch for specific error then I am ok with that!

Comment: You can handle `SqlException` and decide the message based on the `Number` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle [`SqlException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and decide the message based on the [`Number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
Try

    Open the connection and execute command

Catch sqlEx As SqlException
    Select Case sqlEx.Number
        Case -1, 2, 53
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed")
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("General SQL Error Messagge")
    End Select
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("General Error")
End Try
```

You can find a list of errors [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603.aspx).

> - **Error -1**
>     An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be
>     caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not
>     allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 28
> - Server doesn't support requested protocol) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1).
> - **Error 2**
>     An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server, this failure may be
>     caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not
>     allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>     Could not open a connection to SQL Server ) (.Net SqlClient Data
>     Provider)
> - **Error 53**
>     An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server, this failure may be
>     caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not
>     allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>     Could not open a connection to SQL Server ) (.Net SqlClient Data
>     Provider).

Comment: When there is Catch ex As Exception which shows general message then in this case what is the need of "Case Else" messagebox? don't you think it's redundant?

Comment: @Hazmat The first one is a general sql error message and the next is general application error message. For example the first one may be because of having a wrong parameter name or a syntax error in query, the next one could because of divide by zero or something else in your application.

Comment: @Hazmat Also pay attention that the types in catch blocks are different. The first  one is `SqlException` and the next one is `Exception`. Anyway, it is a sample and making the decision is up to you, Hope you find the answer helpful :)

Comment: I don't want a general error for SQL, I want to know what error caused the problem, So I just removed the "Case Else" part remaining things are Okay. and yeah thanks a lot it helped me and I got what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic supports user-filtered exceptions. User-filtered exception handlers catch and handle exceptions based on requirements you define for the exception. These handlers use the Catch statement with the When keyword.You can modify your try catch to filter exceptions as in example,

```
Try

Catch sqlEx as SqlException
   'Do something about the exception
Catch ex as Exception
   Throw 'Re-throw any other exception
End Try
```

also you can deeply filter the exception according to several sql exceptions itself like

```
Try

Catch sqlEx as SqlException When sqlEx.Number = [SQL error number]
   'Do something about the exception
Catch sqlEx as SqlException When sqlEx.Number = [Another SQL error number]
   'Do something about the exception
Catch sqlEx as SqlException  'all other SQL exceptions
   'Do something about the exception
Catch ex as Exception
   Throw 'Re-throw any other exception
End Try
```

for more references,[VB exception filtering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dy8x9k9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [Pros and cons of Exception filtering](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2009/08/25/the-good-and-the-bad-of-exception-filters.aspx), [how to catch sql exception](http://forums.asp.net/t/555900.aspx?How+to+catch+SQL+Exception+)